# how to read a external JSON file into my html/javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am slowly learning JavaScript and am working to build a quiz.

So I have got a very basic quiz see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dPAwT/)

So my specific questiions are

1. How would I store the Questions and answers in an external JSON file?
2. Can I store the Questions and answers in another file type for instance a CSV file?

Maybe I should have a function that goes and gets the Qs&As for me:

```
function getQuestions() {

}
```

A working example where possible would be greatly appreciated.

Other thoughts:
I know the Javascript/HTML quiz could be written alot better here, that is what I am working towards.
I know it could be presented alot better using CSS (currently looking at bootstrap).

Comment: do you want to use a database? I recommend mongodb or couchdb.. because their data structure is very similar to JSON

Comment: If you are just trying to create a simple quiz that could easily be figured out by debugging then its easy and I would gladly paste some helpful code. But if you are creating a web service. Then I don't think anyone is going to paste code here for you because the web service could be written in 1000's of different ways with many different script/programming languages. BTW I didn't down vote you just stating possibly why there is a down vote.

Comment: If he is currently learning JavaScript, I doubt he will be able to handle MongoDB or CouchDB now.

Comment: d3.js can handle CSV files and embedding extra data into HTML elements , where you could hide the "answers" and check them from javascript.  d3 also allows learning graphics.  The O'Reilley book by Scott Murray, Interactive Data Visualization, provides a gentle introduction to this d3 javascript library and actually starts with text/table examples.

Comment: tks for all the comments

Comment: - a simple quiz would be fine to start with @Gorkem Yurtseven - a database is maybe where I am workig towards so maybe a simple example if that exists 

code is fine but sometimes a working example is better as code on its own just leaves me with more questions.
having said that working examples are not always possible.

Comment: @Paul tks for book reccomendation found it [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch06.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to load your file and handle data.

In the `success` function you will have a JSON object.

As for storing data in a CSV file: yes you can, but you would have to [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603242/convert-csv-file-to-json-object-datatable) it

Edit: This approach requires jQuery.

For pure Javascript:

- make an AJAX call to get the contents of the file
- `JSON.parse()` the response.

For making that AJAX call, you should also get familiar with a server-side scripting language.

In php (let's say `getQuiz.php`):

```
<?php
     $data = file_get_contents ('quiz');
     echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

So make a GET request to `getQuiz.php` and the response will be contents of file `quiz` encoded as JSON

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        // Here you have your response
        quiz_data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        // Other code
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getQuiz.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You should definitely clarify that this depends on using jQuery.

Comment: "eval() the response." -- don't!!! Even if `eval` is only a fallback for when `JSON.parse` is not available, you should do some pre-check before doing `eval` (`eval` also kills performance, but who cares about IE7 speed, right?)

Comment: I wrote `eval()`, but used `JSON.parse()` :). You are right. Don't use `eval()`

Answer (score 1):

you can insert a script tag  in head like:

```
<script type="text/json" src="some.cvs" />
```

web browser cant recognize those script tag,so do not download those files.

use jquery or something find those tag's src attribute.use ajax load those file and parse to json data:

```
var eles=$("script[type='text/json']").each(function(){
  var cvsurl=$(this).attr("src");
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: ,
    data: data,
    success: function(result){           
        //handling of your json data
     }
  });
})
```

I just give the method.

Answer (score 0):

you may use jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: [location of your json file],
  data: data,
  success: 
    function(result){           
        //handling of your json data
    }
});
```