# Framework 7 - CSV File read

Tags: android, csv, html-framework-7

Hope you have superb spirit today.

I am newbie with [Framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/). I am creating an application for CSV Reader as i have created same application in Android Native.

I have googled my problem but didnt find anything to use CSV in Framework7.

Is there any link or help?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Please explain more about the issue for us to be able to help you...

Comment: Actually I want to make an application using Fragmework 7, My concept is for sharing quotes which is in Excel or CSV file.
How can i parse this file in Framework 7.

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 does not support parsing of .csv files, it does however support parsing JSON.

Your options:

1. Make your own parsing functionality to convert the csv to arrays. Using for example Javascript `.split()`
2. Find some code on-line which converts csv to for example JSON ([convert csv file to json object datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603242/convert-csv-file-to-json-object-datatable))
3. Convert the csv to JSON on the serverside, for example with PHP